# Sorting transformed XML after determining unique highest score per unique record

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have compiled the following transformation script. It's purpose is to find the highest score for each unique row ID. Sadly, this was creating by piecing together solutions to similar problems, and I do not fully understand the solution. What I am also trying to incorporate into the transformation is to sort the returned records by score descending.

Sample Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" standalone="yes"/>
   <xsl:key name="kRecordByRowID" match="record" use="CON_ROW_ID"/>
   <xsl:template match="record" />
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"> <!-- Insert sort here for partially working sorting--> 
            <xsl:sort select="/SCORE" order="descending"/>        
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="record[count(.|key('kRecordByRowID',CON_ROW_ID)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:for-each select="key('kRecordByRowID',CON_ROW_ID)"> 
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample input:

```
<records>   
    <record>
        <CON_ROW_ID>F</CON_ROW_ID>
        <SCORE>80</SCORE>
    </record>
    <record>
        <CON_ROW_ID>D</CON_ROW_ID>
        <SCORE>90</SCORE>
    </record>
    <record>
        <CON_ROW_ID>D</CON_ROW_ID>
        <SCORE>75</SCORE>
    </record>
    <record>
        <CON_ROW_ID>F</CON_ROW_ID>
        <SCORE>85</SCORE>
    </record>
</records>
```

As you can see in the code, there is a comment that says I can insert the sorting code () into the tags, but it returns incorrect results. The results are sorted to a point, and then they become random.

Where should this sorting code be placed to properly return a score descending list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sadly, this was creating by piecing together solutions to similar
>   problems, and I do not fully understand the solution.

Why don't you rewrite it in a more sensible manner, e.g:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="record-by-ID" match="record" use="CON_ROW_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <!-- for each first record in its group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="records/record[count(.|key('record-by-ID',CON_ROW_ID)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- sort the group by score -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('record-by-ID',CON_ROW_ID)">
                <xsl:sort select="SCORE" order="descending"/>   
                <!-- output the highest scoring record -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Edit

> It should take the highest score for each unique CON_ROW_ID, and then
>   return these again in SCORE descending order.

If your processor supports some basic EXSLT functions, then this could be very short and sweet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math"
extension-element-prefixes="set math">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="record-by-ID" match="record" use="CON_ROW_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="set:distinct(records/record/CON_ROW_ID)">
            <xsl:sort select="math:max(key('record-by-ID', .)/SCORE)" order="descending"/>   
            <xsl:copy-of select="math:highest(key('record-by-ID', .)/SCORE)/parent::record"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Otherwise you'll need to do this in two passes (*and* use the EXSLT node-set() function in the process):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="record-by-ID" match="record" use="CON_ROW_ID"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- FIRST PASS -->
    <xsl:variable name="highest-scoring-records">
        <!-- for each first record in its group -->
        <xsl:for-each select="records/record[count(.|key('record-by-ID',CON_ROW_ID)[1]) = 1]">
            <!-- sort the group by score -->
            <xsl:for-each select="key('record-by-ID',CON_ROW_ID)">
                <xsl:sort select="SCORE" order="descending"/>   
                <!-- output the highest scoring record -->
                <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <!-- OUTPUT -->
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($highest-scoring-records)/record">
            <xsl:sort select="SCORE" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This definitely makes the code more legible and understandable. I have tried placing the sorting tag to sort the final results in terms of score in a few places and so far have had no luck. An example of the output I get is "(D,90),(E,90),(B,85),(F,85),(C,80),(A,90),(J,85),(G,80)". I have put them as pairs to make it a bit easier to read. It seems like the sort works at first, and then goes wrong.

Comment: @Strzelec Do you mean you want to have yet another sort of the highest-scoring records only?

Comment: That is correct. It should take the highest score for each unique CON_ROW_ID, and then return these again in SCORE descending order. My apologies if that was not clear.

Comment: @Strzelec I have added two alternative approaches to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `/SCORE` element (it will never be selected by `sort`). What you want is to use the contextual `SCORE` element in `record`, so that would be simply `SCORE`.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"> <!-- Insert sort here for partially working sorting--> 
            <xsl:sort select="SCORE" order="descending"/>        
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```